# Alignment ampersand within \underbrace

Tags: pdftex, amsmath

I have the following equation:

```tex
$\neg(A \wedge \neg A) \vee (B \implies A)$ \\
$\neg(A \wedge \neg A) \vee (\neg B \vee A)$ \\
$\underbrace{\underbrace{(\neg A \vee A)}_\text{w} \vee (\neg B \vee A)}_\text{w}$
```

I want to align them around the ∨ (`\vee`) symbol.

I tried the following:

```tex
\begin{align*}
    \neg(A \wedge \neg A) &\vee (B \implies A) \\
    \neg(A \wedge \neg A) &\vee (\neg B \vee A) \\
    \underbrace{\underbrace{(\neg A \vee A)}_\text{w} &\vee (\neg B \vee A)}_\text{w}
\end{align*}
```

but it spits out the rather cryptic error message:

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.73 \end{align*}
```

Line 73 in this case is the last line of my example code in this question.

I think the problem may be because the `&` appears inside the `\underbrace`. Is it possible to still align these equations and keep the `\underbrace`?

Comment: You can use the [`luamathalign`](https://ctan.org/pkg/luamathalign) package (requires LuaTeX).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `tikzmark`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \neg(A \wedge \neg A) &\vee (B \implies A) \\
    \neg(A \wedge \neg A) &\vee (\neg B \vee A) \\
    \underbrace{\tikzmark{V1}(\neg A \vee A)}_\mathrm{w} &\vee (\neg B \vee A)\tikzmark{V2}
\end{align*}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[decorate, decoration={calligraphic brace, mirror, amplitude=5pt}, line width=1.2pt] 
    ([yshift=-4ex]{pic cs:V1}) --node[below=.5ex]{\scriptsize w} ([yshift=-4ex]{pic cs:V2});
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That did the trick, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If it's possible to use LuaTeX, then the [`luamathalign`](https://ctan.org/pkg/luamathalign) package can be used to solve this problem elegantly. It only requires replacing `&` with `\AlignHere` inside the `\underbrace`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{luamathalign}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \neg(A \wedge \neg A) &\vee (B \implies A) \\
    \neg(A \wedge \neg A) &\vee (\neg B \vee A) \\
    \underbrace{\underbrace{(\neg A \vee A)}_\text{w} \AlignHere\vee (\neg B \vee A)}_\text{w}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The spacing around the middle `\vee` in the third row looks a bit too small.

Comment: `\underbrace` makes a math operator; add braces around it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use LuaLaTeX, then `luamathalign` is the best choice. Here's a fixed version, where instead of `\underbrace` I use the defined command `\ubrace` that avoids a shortcoming of `\underbrace` as regards to spacing.

The second version runs with every engine.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{luamathalign} % for the first realization, requires LuaLaTeX

\newcommand{\ubrace}[2]{{\underbrace{#1}_{#2}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \neg(A \wedge \neg A) &\vee (B \Rightarrow A) \\
  \neg(A \wedge \neg A) &\vee (\neg B \vee A) \\
  \ubrace{\ubrace{(\neg A \vee A)}{\text{w}}
      \AlignHere \vee (\neg B \vee A)}{\text{w}}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  \neg(A \wedge \neg A) &\vee (B \Rightarrow A) \\
  \neg(A \wedge \neg A) &\vee (\neg B \vee A) \\
  \ubrace{(\neg A \vee A)}{\text{w}} & \vee (\neg B \vee A) \\[-3.5ex]
  &% here the tricky part
  \sbox{0}{$\displaystyle{}\vee (\neg B \vee A)$}
  \makebox[\wd0][r]{%
    $\displaystyle
    \ubrace{\phantom{(\neg A \vee A)\vee(\neg B \vee A)}}{\text{w}}
    $%
  }
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `_\text{w}` only works by chance and that the correct syntax is

```
_{\text{w}}
```